# jsonp callback function name can't be identified in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonp

use ajax to transfer jsonp data by jsonp function "callback1"

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#link').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:2000',
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonp: "callback1",
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#result').val('my name is ' + data.name);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

below is server side

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var port = 2000;
var data = { 'name': 'ss', 'age': 10 };
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var params = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (params.query && params.query.callback) {
    console.log(params.query);
    var str = params.query.callback1 + '(' +JSON.stringify(data)+')';
    console.log(str);
    res.end(str);
  } else {
    res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
  }

}).listen(port,function(){
  console.log('server is listening on port ' + port);
});
```

attached is the error i got in chrome console. 
[image]

but when i change Ajax in this way:`jsonp: "callback"`
and modify server code in this way：

```
var str = params.query.callback + '(' +JSON.stringify(data)+')';
```

it can work.

can anyone help check why i can't use other jsonp function name other than 'callback'?

Comment: You made a typo (voting to close as off-topic). You keep swapping between `callback` and `callback1`. Pick one name and stick to it. https://i.imgur.com/qjHXeXl.png

Comment: This is 2017. There is no good reason to use JSONP. Browsers have excellent support for CORS which is better in every way.

Comment: thank you for pointing out. May I ask what tech can replace jsonp in CORS? i am an amateur and now is learning node.js and express.

Comment: CORS **is** the replacement for JSONP

Comment: got it. thanks a lot.